# Set search value in native query

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have this Spring JPA native query:

```
@Query (value =
            "SELECT d.id AS id...........
                    "FROM deals_new d " +
                    "WHERE ( " +
                    "        e.first_name LIKE '%:param%' " +
                    "        OR e.last_name LIKE '%:param%' " +
                    ") " +
                    "OFFSET :offset " +
                    "LIMIT :limit ",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<ResultDTO> getHistory(                                                   
                                                  @Param("param") String username,
                                                  @Param("offset") int offset,
                                                  @Param("limit") int limit);
```

What is the proper way to set search param? As you can see now it's hardcoded and set unproperly. Can you advice what is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use named placeholders like `?1`, `?2` etc.,

```
e.first_name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?1, '%')
```

Comment: Can you show me how I have to edit the code, please?

Comment: Thanks for the update. But how I have to send this param from here `@Param("param") String username`?